# How to mock out a model in angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a function that accepts a model as an input

```
  selectFault(fault: Fault) {
    this.faultsService.setSelectedFault(fault)
      this.router.navigate(['fault-detail']);

  }
```

I have generated a test for it, but it is complaining about the faultstub

```
error TS2693: 'Fault' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

the line it is complaining about is

```
 { provide: Fault, useValue: faultStub }
```

the whole test is below for completeness

so how do I go about newing up a Fault to pass to my function?

```
let component: Tab1Page;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<Tab1Page>;
  beforeEach(() => {
    const routerStub = { navigate: () => ({}) };
    const faultsServiceStub = {
      getFaults: () => ({ subscribe: () => ({}) }),
      invalidateCache: () => ({}),
      setSelectedFault: () => ({})
    };
    const faultStub = {};
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      declarations: [Tab1Page],
      providers: [
        { provide: Router, useValue: routerStub },
        { provide: FaultsService, useValue: faultsServiceStub },
        { provide: Fault, useValue: faultStub }
      ]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Tab1Page);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });
  it('can load instance', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
  describe('selectFault', () => {
    it('makes expected calls', () => {
      const routerStub: Router = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Router);
      const faultsServiceStub: FaultsService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(
        FaultsService
      );
      const faultStub: Fault = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Fault);
      spyOn(routerStub, 'navigate');
      spyOn(faultsServiceStub, 'setSelectedFault');
      component.selectFault(faultStub);
      expect(routerStub.navigate).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(faultsServiceStub.setSelectedFault).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

and this is my fault

```
export interface Fault {
  description: string;
  title: string;
  assignee_id: Number;
  id: string;

}
```

Comment: is `Fault` a class or an interface ?

Comment: it is in interface export interface Fault, I have updated the question

Comment: ahhh got you, thanks

Comment: why are you using a provider for te Fault? It is not getting injected in the service right? You can just use it as a object in the test right?

Comment: @JaChNo : your component does not depend on your model `Fault`. It means you have no need to declare it in `providers` array. Your interface's properties are not nullable, so make sure to create an object with every property of `Fault` when you call your `selectFault` in your tests.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove `{ provide: Fault, useValue: faultStub }` . You dont have to inject interface in `providers`
2. Remove `const faultStub: Fault = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Fault);` . You can simply define a value and pass it something as below:

   ```
   it('makes expected calls', () => {
     const routerStub: Router = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Router);
     const faultsServiceStub: FaultsService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(
       FaultsService
     );
     const faultStub: Fault = { id: '1', assignee_id : 11 , title : 'Test Title', description: 'Sample Description' };
     spyOn(routerStub, 'navigate');
     spyOn(faultsServiceStub, 'setSelectedFault');
     component.selectFault(faultStub);
     expect(routerStub.navigate).toHaveBeenCalled();
     expect(faultsServiceStub.setSelectedFault).toHaveBeenCalled();
   });
   ```